# calculateDropLocation not working

Tags: apache-flex, air, drag-and-drop

I have this `<s:list>` with an itemrenderer and arraycollection as dataprovider.
Now my problem is I want to be able to drag and drop to reorder those items.

To do so I need to know the dragged item index, and the drop location.
I have the selected item index but when I want to calculate my drop location using this code in my `dragcompletehandler()`...

```
var dropLocal:DropLocation = listfiles.layout.calculateDropLocation(event);
trace (event.currentTarget.selectedIndex + "," + dropLocal.dropIndex);
```

It always returns me the number 3 and not the correct drop locations index.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The list shouild drag and drop for you.  Set dragEnabled=true, dropEnabled=true, and dragMoveEnabled=true and you're done.  Dragging from within the list will reorder it.

If you want to manually implement the drop, you should do your work on a dragDrop handler, as that only executes on a valid dragDrop.  The dragComplete event fires even if there was no valid drop (dropping the item when a component was not marked to accept the drag).

Answer (score 0):

calculateDropLocation always returns the last row. The code is incomplete as of 4.6.

The x,y coordinates are not event used. If you step into it you will find what I did.

Override or call your own calculateDropLocation() function.